# nodejs modules not installed in the proper place

Tags: node.js, module

I am using nodjs 0.10.12 in Windows server 2012. I succesfully installed node using `msi` installer. I tried to install `pg`, `websockets`, `url`, and `policyfile`, using `npm install (name of module)`.

But, modules got installed in `C\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache`, I guessed they will be installed in `C\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules`, just like in another project I did.

Anyway I was getting the error

```
module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'websocket'
```

I used this `C\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules npm install websocket --force` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152635/node-js-websocket-module-installed-but-wont-work-in-scripts). Worked for websocket, but now, I was getting the error for pg. Used the `--force` for pg and got the error for the url. Fixed it with `--force`, got the error for policyfile, also fixed it with `--force`.

Now I get no errors and my website works fine.

But :

1-Files of those modules are still in `C\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache`.

2-In the console, when I start the server , I get `warning native modules not compiled. xor performance will be degraded` and `warning native modules not compiled. utf-8 validation disabled`.

Is this wrong? Will they affect my system/project? Did I messed up big time? Should I delete the extra folders? Please advice

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which directory do you have your project files? The directory you execute npm command is important.  Did you run npm command from the project directory?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too. Turns out I simply mistyped the name of the install. When you install the websocket from the Node.js comand prompt, make sure you spell it correctly, i.e. `npm install websocket` (not websockets with an 's'). You can check your previous spelling by looking in the `node_modules` folder where ever you initially installed the module on, presumably on the root drive for your user. (`C:/Users/<mynamehere>/node_modules/`)

If this was the case, don't bother trying to simply change the name of the folder name to `websocket`, it didn't work for me. Delete the folder and reinstall the module websocket through the node.js command prompt. I hope this helps, there are other solutions floating around in regards to globally specified installs and correct folder directory for where these installs were made, either of these could also be your solution, depending.