# Node.js, getting cannot find module 'ws' error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have installed node.js on my Windows-7 PC. I am not able to create websocket connection to a remote server.

I tried to load modeule "ws" in my script :

```
var WebSocket = require('ws')
```

It gave an error :

```
cannot find module 'ws'
```

So I followed instructions over here :  [node.js websocket module installed but won't work in scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152635/node-js-websocket-module-installed-but-wont-work-in-scripts)

```
Execute cmd as Administrator (Right click cmd icon-> Run as Administrator) Then type in cmd:

c:\Node Instalation Dir\> npm install -g express
c:\Node Instalation Dir\> npm install websocket --force

Then run my script :--
D:\My Script Folder \> node myscript.js
```

Again same error. What could be the problem ?

```
cannot find module 'ws'
```

Comment: Run the npm install command inside of your script folder. Also, I think it should be "npm install ws".

Comment: Also you need to add the node installation directory to your global environment variable "PATH" in order to use the command as-is when the command-line path is different than that directory. Unless you do that you need to specify the full working path to the npm executable when you run the command outside of the directory ex. c:\myscript> c:\nodeinstall\npm.exe install ws

Answer (score 28):

If you install websocket, you should require websocket, not ws:

```
npm install websocket
```

Then in REPL:

```
var websocket = require('websocket');
```

Alternatively, you can use `ws` module:

```
npm install ws
```

Repl/script:

```
var ws = require('ws');
```

---

Take a look at your `node_modules` directory (only the first level, the dirs right beneath it). You can require each of them by exact name.

`require` will actually look for a `node_modules` in current dir, then if not found, then the parent and again parent etc. If it doesn't find it, it will look for modules installed in global path pointed to by `NODE_PATH`. (And of course, native modules such as `http` and `net`.)

Answer (score 5):

Try to install the package locally but not globally, i.e. without the `-g` option.

> Have you installed the module with the -g option? I think that not every module is meant to be installed globally, instead, try installing it locally for the project you are creating (npm install), and check if the error persists. [...]
>
> If you want to just require('something'); it is better to install it locally, otherwise, you have to require('{PREFIX}something'), where prefix is the path to where yo have installed it globally. Check out this [blog post](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/) , and, as it says, generally the rule of thumb is to install things locally if you are going to use them in your app, and globally if you are going to use them from the command line.

[node error cannot find module already installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704660/node-error-cannot-find-module-already-installed).

Comment: this link worked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874582/change-default-global-installation-directory-for-node-js-modules-in-windows ... ichanged the path to fetch the module 'ws'  .... var WebSocket = require('C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\ws');

Comment: @Katoch Just because it works doesn't mean it's the best practice to do.

Comment: then what could be the solution ... ?

Comment: also performed --- npm install ws

Comment: I appreciate your prompt answer

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your project root directory and open the package.json file and edit
2. Add "type":"module";
3. Go to the top of your js file, delete the require and use the import statement to import 'ws' into your script.

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing the same issue.

**Error 1:**

[image]

Just simply trying `npm install ws` to the same folder level where I had my server.js worked for me.

[image]

**Error 2:**

- If you are getting the error `WebSocket is not defined`, then try the command `npm install ws`, after adding the below code. if `ws` doesn't work then try `npm install websocket`

Also, add this in your file:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9090');
```

[image]

[image]